# Modify UITabBarController while using Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am a little newer at storyboarding. I have a UITabBarController in my story board as the entry point in my application. I tied all the other view controllers to the tab bar controller. Everything works perfectly fine. I now want to do some very basic interface, colors, opacity, text, images, etc.

This may sound like a very basic question but how can I access my UITabBarController to be able to set my values. What is he best place to be doing these modifications: appDelegate since that one tabbarcontroller controls all of the controllers for the entire app?

**What I have tried already**
I created a new class as  UITabBarController and I tied it to the UITabBarController in the StoryBoard by setting it as a custom class.
I couldn't figure out how to access the UITabBarController to make any customizations.

Comment: The things you're trying to customize are ones that should belong to individual view controllers rather than the tab bar controller.  Is there a problem with modifying them in their own controllers' `viewDidLoad` methods?

Comment: @PhillipMills I am trying to adjust the properties of the UITabBarController itself. Is the tab bar accessible from the individual view controllers? I also want to keep the tab bar consistent among all views. If I make the adjustment on the 1st view controller will it stay that way for all other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the controller using something like:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)[[appDelegate window] rootViewController];
```

(Adding code to test that it really is a `UITabBarController` before using it would be a good idea.)

Alternatively, if your tab bar controller is a custom sub-class of `UITabBarController`, it would be cleaner to use its `viewDidLoad` to modify its own properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!!!  I was trying everything last night and I couldnt figure out how to access my existing TabBarController. I will test it tongiht and accept the answer.